# Text not fiting properly inside of div on smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, text

I have a div with an image in it and next to it some text. I want the text to fit properly into the box, which works fine with my normal screen size. Unfortunatly the text overflows the box if I look at the webiste in 1280x720 (smaller screen size).

This is how my website look in 1440x2560[image]

This is how it looks in 1280x720 [image]

This is the CSS:

```
.head-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

 .container {
    background-color: #F6E9DA;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left:50px;
    display: flex;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 250ms;
    scale: 0.9;
}

.container2 {
    background-color: #F6E9DA;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    display: flex;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 250ms;
    scale: 0.9;
    margin-left: 100px;
}


 .description p {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #617569;
}

 .description h2 {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    color: #617569;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="head-container">

                   
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="images/sampleFace.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br>
                        sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
                        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
                        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>
                        Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <br>
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
                        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>
                        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    </div>
    

                </div>
                    

                <div class="container2">

                    <div class="photo">
                        <img src="images/sampleFace2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br>
                        sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
                        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
                        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>
                        Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <br>
                        tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
                        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>
                        no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    </div>
    

                </div>

                </div>
```

I tried setting a fixed height for the div that the text is in but that didnt work. I'm looking for a solution which works universally on any screen size.

Comment: now i made changes in my answer i solve this by two way, both are working, try it, comment if any query

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities:

- you let the box grow to fit the text
- you cut the text which overflow
- you decrease text size
  ...
  or a combination of the 3 depending of media query values

For the third one you can use clamp(), see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp

You can combine 1 and 2.
So you can cut the text which overflow with text-overflow (take care of the browser option compatibilities), see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

You add an event on the ellipsis (button?), to let the box increase

Answer (score 0):

Fixed example in action: https://codepen.io/sudhxnva/pen/RwJVjde

You don't need to use relative positioning to set the containers to where you want them to be, plus you need to add your `align-items` and `justify-content` styles to the element you're setting `flex` to i.e your head container. So your CSS can look something like this:

```css
.head-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

 .container {
    background-color: #F6E9DA;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 1200px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 250ms;
    scale: 0.9;
    padding: 40px;
}


 .description p {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #617569;
}

 .description h2 {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    color: #617569;
 }
```

As you'll notice, I've removed the `container2` class because you don't need it. They can share the same classes as they aren't being positioned relatively to the parent element anymore. Just set both containers to the `container` class and you should be good to go

Answer (score -1):

1. use overflow:auto so both container will auto scroll show when something is overflow .

```css
.head-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

 .container {
    background-color: #F6E9DA;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left:50px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 250ms;
    scale: 0.9;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2%;
}

.container2 {
    background-color: #F6E9DA;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 250ms;
    scale: 0.9;
    margin-left: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2%;
}



.description p {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #617569;
}

 .description h2 {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    color: #617569;
 }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="head-container">

                   
  <div class="container">

      <div class="photo">
          <img src="images/sampleFace.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="description">
          <h2>test </h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br>
          sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
          aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>
          Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <br>
          tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>
          no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>


  </div>
      

  <div class="container2">

      <div class="photo">
          <img src="images/sampleFace2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="description">
          <h2>test</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br>
          sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
          aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>
          Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <br>
          tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>
          no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>


  </div>

  </div>
```

2. use @media css for container display:block when they are comes to small screen.

```css
.head-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

 .container {
    background-color: #F6E9DA;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left:50px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 250ms;
    scale: 0.9;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2%;
}

.container2 {
    background-color: #F6E9DA;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    height: 450px;
    width: 1200px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 250ms;
    scale: 0.9;
    margin-left: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2%;
}



.description p {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: #617569;
}

 .description h2 {
    font-family: "Poppins";
    font-size: 26px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    color: #617569;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width:1200px)
 {
  .head-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .container
  {
    width:80vw;
  }
  .container2
  {
    width: 80vw;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
 }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<div class="head-container">

                   
  <div class="container">

      <div class="photo">
          <img src="images/sampleFace.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="description">
          <h2>test </h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br>
          sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
          aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>
          Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <br>
          tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>
          no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>


  </div>
      

  <div class="container2">

      <div class="photo">
          <img src="images/sampleFace2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="description">
          <h2>test</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,<br>
          sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna<br>
          aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.<br>
          Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod <br>
          tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br>
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,<br>
          no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>


  </div>

  </div>
```

comment if any query